# CURL SSL3 Empty Reply from server Error No: 52

Tags: php, curl, ssl

I've searched almost every thread but nothing happened. I'm trying to connect an SSL3 oracle web service with PHP. I've tried soapclient and nusoap but nothing worked. Also, i've added ssl_method to  SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3 but still got the error.

I've switched to curl and added the ssl version to 3, added header with expect, added mozilla.pem file and also tried with the clients certificate with the option `CURLOPT_CAINFO`. Setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` worked for the hello but I still get the same error.

The code is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$query= 'http://somesecretclienturl.com/?with=some&parameters=here';        
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$query);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(empty($result)){
    print_r(curl_error($ch));
}else{ 
    print_r('success'); //Never came to this point
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Note: I can connect to web service and get a response when i try:
`curl -i http://somesecretclienturl.com/?with=some&parameters=here` from terminal.

Comment: Your code doesn't run. Shows syntax error.

Comment: Sorry for that, fixed it.

Comment: If your curl's commandline really works then you don't need to use `SSL...` curl options from php. Does your url starts with `https://`? If so, then I believe your `curl-commandline` is nicely configured with openssl.

Comment: **Never, EVER disable peer verification** unless you don't care about the security of what you're transmitting. Also, unless you're *sure* the remote server is using the (outdated and relatively insecure) SSLv3 protocol then don't bother setting the `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` option).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @SabujHassan . Yes the webservice starts with https and i can get the results if i try with the browser. Also the ssl certificate seems fine.There is problem only with getting results with php. It always returns 0 byte of data when i check the curl info.

Thanks rdlowrey the webservice is reachable only with vpn connection so the security won't be an issue. If i don't disable the vertification it stops while handshake.